# Enforcing C++98/03 for clang

Tags: c++, clang, c++98

The following code is [rejected](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HxWMLhQNJfw3F0Kj) by latest gcc with `-std=c++98` option enabled:

```
#include <random>
int main() {}
```

due to the c++11 nature of `<random>` header. But clang [accepts](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FIfDrBjBOdIocwAi) it with no warning/error.

Is there a way to say clang to use the c++98/03 standard only? Maybe a bug?

Comment: Unfortunately most compilers seem to allow non standard elements by default (no idea why). On `GCC` to force standard compliance you need the `-pedantic-errors` flag. Maybe its the same for `clang++`?

Comment: "Maybe a bug?" - Definitely a bug. One that's unlikely to be caught since legacy code won't actually include modern headers

Comment: @YSC from the clang's point of view - maybe... Did clang exist in '03?

Comment: @StoryTeller: What exactly makes it a bug? If `<random>` is surrounded by one huge `#if __cplusplus > 199711L`, making it effectively empty in C++98, I'd be hard-pressed to find wording in C++98 making that a bug.

Comment: @MSalters - If only... https://wandbox.org/permlink/atmIpYn3tYY1e040

Comment: @StoryTeller: Now that seems like a valid edit of the question. As it currently stands, the question is whether `#include <random>` should be rejected outright in C++98 mode.

Comment: I don't see why it should; it would make the validity of #include directives dependent on whether include files have suffixes or not, something of which IIRC C++ has no notion of (you can have a file called ``random`` in your user-defined include path and it's a valid header).